# One dimensional array pseudocode?

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

can `array[1:30]` be an one dimensional `array`?

Also how do you print two `arrays` next to each other? (in pseudocode)

```
PRINT array[1:30],arraytwo[1:30]
```

^is this ok?

Comment: The syntax of pseudocode is whatever the hell you want it to be. As long as it gets the point across and doesn't take too much work to understand, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an already-defined syntax then follow its definition. Otherwise it's up to you:

```
Let "array" be one-dimensional array of 30 elements.
Let "arraytwo" be one-dimensional array of 30 elements.
Print "array" and "arraytwo" concatenated.
```

In fact, [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) is not for machines but for humans, so just make it understandable to humans.